# How can $e^x$ be restated for small $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, periodic-functions

Suppose I have the following equation:

\begin{equation}
1=\frac{S_0}{\gamma}(1-e^{-\gamma T_n})+\lambda\int^{t_{n+1}}_{t_n}e^{-\gamma(t_{n+1}-\tau)}g(\tau)d\tau.
\end{equation}

If I make two assumptions

1. g is a periodic function with period $T$ and mean zero.
2. $\gamma$ is small

somehow my equation changes to this:

$$
1=S_0T_n+\lambda\int^{t_{n+1}}_{t_n}g(\tau)d\tau-\lambda \gamma \int^{t_{n+1}}_{t_n}(t_{n+1}-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau.
$$

How is this restatement of the equation achieved?

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Do you mean to use "$\approx$" instead of "$=$" here? I ask because if $g\equiv 0$, the integrals vanish, and it seems unlikely that the stuff outside of the integrals in these equations is equal...

Comment: I would guess this is only an approximation, using a linear approximation of $e^x$ near $0$ of $e^x \approx 1 + x$ (the first two terms of the Taylor series).

Comment: @MPW that's possible.  the author uses equals signs.  (and i confirmed for myself that constant functions are periodic, so your reasoning with $g=0$ i see makes sense.)

Comment: @MPW yeah, that's it.  that approximation solves it.

Comment: Good deal ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is thanks to @MPW.

The restatement depends on the approximation

$$
e^x\approx x+1,
$$

which holds for small $x$.  Here, the relevant small variable is $\gamma$.